# Notification for account association with other SE sites persist no matter what action I take

Tags: support, notification-bar

The aforementioned notification is always annoying me on any SE site I log in other than the original SE site where I first stared, Ask Ubuntu. Clicking on either of the links has no effect and will show up on the next page, and dismissing the notification works as normal to only dismiss it on the current page.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page after dismissing the notification with the "X"?

Comment: @ChrisF OMG! Yep, doing that solved the problem. I can't believe, such a persistent annoyance done away so easily... Anyway, situation resolved, if you wish to, please post that in the answer and I'll use it to close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing the page after dismissing the notification with the "X"?

*posted by request*